# 2004 Durango making bad noise after driving in D2

Tags: troubleshooting, transmission, noise, dodge, durango

My son accidentally drove my 2004 Durango in D2 at around 50 mph for 20 minutes. It was running right around 3000 rpm. Now it's making a low whirring noise which gets louder the faster I go. When I slow down, the noise is still there, but at a really low pitch. It's shifting fine, but I'm worried something major is about to break. It's got 153,000 miles, but runs well. Transmission seems to be holding up just fine. We're hoping to make a major drive from Maine to Florida in a month. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the noise change at all when the transmission shifts? Or does the pitch just continue to climb the faster the vehicle goes? Also, is this a 4x4 or 2wd? Coming from Maine, I'd bet 4x4, but hate to assume.